How to change the value of a tkinter scale after already setting default value
I have set the default value to zero. I put a demonstration of what im doing below, but to sum it up I want a function to change the position of the scale to be at 0.5, not change the default value. How could I do that without making the user manually scroll?
def function():
   time_scale.set(0.5)

# Create time control
time_label = ttk.Label(window, text="Time")
time_scale = ttk.Scale(window, from_=0.0, to=1.0, orient="horizontal", command=set_time)
time_scale.set(0)  # Set initial volume value


The code you posted appears to do exactly what you want it to do.  In what way does it fail to meet your needs?

Calling set does not change a default value, it sets the current value. The code you've posted does exactly what you want.
The scale doesn't really have the concept of a default value. It only has one value associated with it, which is whatever the current value is. So, in your code the current value starts at 0, and when you call the function it becomes 0.5.
